# How to check if multiple values exists in a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like that:

```
word_freq = {
"Hello": 56,
"at": 23,
"test": 43,
"this": 78
```

}

and a list of values `list_values = [val1, val2]`

I need to check that all the `values: val1 and val2` in `list_values` exist as values in `word_freq` dict.

I tried to solve the problem withis function:

```
def check_value_exist(test_dict, value1, value2):
    list_values = [value1, value2]
    do_exist = False
    for key, value in test_dict.items():
       for i in range(len(list_values)):
           if value == list_values[i]:
               do_exist = True
    return do_exist
```

There must be a straightforward way to do it, but i'm still new to python and can't figure it out. tried if booth values in word_freq, didn't work.

Comment: `exist = all( v in test_dict for v in [value1,value2] )`

Comment: Look up `all(...)`.

Comment: Are you checking for values or keys? From the code and the question text it seems is values.

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you want:

```
def check_value_exist(test_dict, value1, value2):
    return all( v in test_dict for v in [value1,value2] )
```

Comment: What about a `def check_value_exist(test_dict, *values): return all( v in test_dict for v in values)` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a more flexible solution.  I sometimes hesitate to suggest advanced techniques in what might be a school assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Make `values` a set and you can use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) to verify all values are in the `dict`:

```
def check_value_exist(word_freq, *values):
    return set(values).issubset(word_freq)

print(check_value_exists(word_freq, 'at', 'test'))
print(check_value_exists(word_freq, 'at', 'test', 'bar'))
```

---

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
def check_value_exist(test_dict, value1, value2):
    return {value1, value2} <= set(test_dict.values())


print(check_value_exist(word_freq, 23, 56))
print(check_value_exist(word_freq, 23, 42))
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

Since you receive the values as parameters you could build a set and verify that the set is a subset of the dict values.

If you are checking for keys, instead of values this should be enough:

```
def check_value_exist(test_dict, value1, value2):
    return {value1, value2} <= test_dict.keys()
```